# Highcharts center series inside solidgauge

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have 2 `solidgauge` charts with text that is shown on hovering over one of them. Here is a screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

As you can see in the screenshot attached the text is not centered horizontally. the text should look something like that:

```
first one
   50%
```

but it looks like this:

```
first one
50%
```

JS:

```
Highcharts.chart('chart', {
    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge',
        height: '110%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Title',
        style: {
            fontSize: '24px',
            textAlign: 'center'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        backgroundColor: 'none',
        shadow: false,
        style: {
            fontSize: '16px',
            textAlign: 'center'
        },
        valueSuffix: '%',
        pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y}</span>',
        positioner: function (labelWidth) {
            return {
                x: (this.chart.chartWidth - labelWidth) / 2,
                y: (this.chart.plotHeight / 2) + 15
            };
        }
    },
    pane: {
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        background: [{
            outerRadius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '88%',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0, 0.3)',
            borderWidth: 0
        }, {
            outerRadius: '87%',
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(50,0,10, 0.3)',
            borderWidth: 0
        }]
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickPositions: []
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
            },
            linecap: 'round',
            stickyTracking: false,
            rounded: true
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'first one',
        data: [{
            color: 'rgba(0,0,0)',
            radius: '112%',
            innerRadius: '88%',
            y: 50,
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'second one',
        data: [{
            color: 'rgba(50,0,10)',
            radius: '87%',
            innerRadius: '63%',
            y: 80,
        }]
    },]
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chart" style="width:500px;height:500px;margin:auto;"></div>
```

Here is a fiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/Lpyq6xt4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tooltip.pointFormatter` in combination with `tooltip.useHTML` to be able to style the text and center it:

```js
...
tooltip: {
  ...
  useHTML: true,
  pointFormatter: function() {
    console.log(this);
    return `
      <div style="width: 200px; text-align: center;">
        ${this.series.name}<br><span style="font-size:2em; color: ${this.color}; font-weight: bold">${this.y}</span>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}
...
```

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uzx1angd/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.useHTML